# Why can't we send attachments in the message exchanges on Career stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, jobs

Why in the message exchanges on [career stackoverflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) one cannot send attachments? I know its not an email service but its handy sometimes when conversing with employers.

**Update [June 2015]**: The feature is now available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll keep an eye on this as it feels like a nice-to-have type feature right now.  Communication between candidates and employers is core to our product, however as you mentioned, we do not seek to be a full email service.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Actually that's what happened. An employer requested for additional resume and portfolio. I have it in the form of docs. I would have to upload it somewhere on the cloud and give a link to him, which doesn't seem quite comfortable. Other way is to shift our conversation to an another email service. So I don't see why you won't want the users to just initiate the conversations there and then shift to another service to follow up? Also I guess an email service would do much more than just including attachments.